# MySql get previous rows byTimeStamp

Tags: mysql

I have:

Table infoUpdate
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+ 
 
| idKey1|  idKey2   |      **__date_Update_**      |  DayWeek  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1___     | **__*3*__*_*_**         |  2013.01.01 15:00:00  |   2       |
| 1___    |  **__*3*__*_*_**         |  2013.01.01 18:00:00  |   2       |
| 1___     |  **__*3*__*_*_**         |  2013.01.02 15:00:00  |   3       |
| 1___     | **__*3*__*_*_**         |  2013.01.02 18:00:00  |   3       |
| 1___     |  **__*3*__*_*_**         |  2013.01.03 15:00:00  |   4       |
| 1___     |  **__*3*__*_*_**         |  2013.01.03 18:00:00  |   4       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

How to obtain only previous rows by timeStamp

Select * FROM infoUpdate if where date_Update <='2013.01.03 18:00:00';

This is what I'm looking at obtaining:

+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+  
| idKey1|  idKey2   |      date_Update      |  DayWeek  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+  
| 1     | 3         |  2013.01.01 18:00:00  |   2       |
| 1     | 3         |  2013.01.02 18:00:00  |   3       |
| 1     | 3         |  2013.01.03 18:00:00  |   4       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

Comment: Remove the `if` from your query.

Answer (score 1):

will this work for you

```
 Select * FROM infoUpdate  where date_Update >= DATE_SUB( '2013.01.03 18:00:00' ,INTERVAL 90 DAY )
```

this will give you 90 days records previous to the date mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you:

```
Select idKey1, idKey2 , DayWeek, MAX(dateUpdate) as dateUpdate
FROM infoUpdate 
where date_Update <='2013.01.03 18:00:00'
GROUP BY idKey1, idKey2 , DayWeek, DATE(dateUpdate);
```

If you are interested in last week data only, `DATE(dateUpdate)` can be removed from `GROUP BY`.

Comment: TimeStamp may be any example 2013.01.03 15:00:00 ?

Comment: I copied timestamp from the question. sure, it can be anything